# why Recipient ID of QBDialog is always null but has 2 different opponent Id in Quickblox

Tags: android, chat, quickblox, quickblox-android

I am implementing Quickblox for the first time. I don`t know why my  Recipient id is null even if I have set opponent id.I am getting this in chat Activity of Simple chat module.

This is callack in QB sdk
**qbChatDialog.initForChat(QBChatService.getInstance());**

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.saffron.hq/com.saffron.hq.chat.ChatActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Recipient ID can't be null or empty
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Recipient ID can't be null or empty
            at com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatDialog.initForChat(Unknown Source)
            at com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatDialog.initForChat(Unknown Source)
            at com.saffron.hq.chat.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.java:108)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)